# How to get the worker info of a task id in JStorm?

Tags: worker, jstorm

When I'm implementing a `CustomStreamGrouping`, the `WorkerTopologyContext context` can tell me `getThisWorkerTasks()` and one task id's component.

But how could I get not only `ThisWorker`'s tasks, but I want to know every task id's worker info.

There seems no `worker id` to identify worker instance. So is there a way to get all the workers' hosts and ports as well? And a way to know one task id is in which worker?